# There are $3$ blue card, $4$ green and $2$ white card in a bag. What is the probability of getting blue card three times?

Tags: probability

There are $3$ blue card, $4$ green and $2$ white card in a bag. What is the probability of getting blue card three times?

I've found it as

$$P = \frac {3}{9}$$

Comment: Can you please show your work? Is this with replacement or without? Are you drawing exactly three cards from the bag or more?

Comment: Yes, let me show. My work: There are 9 card in total. By the way, I've gotten that $\frac {3}{9}$. It says three times. That's why I doubt it.

Comment: So you're simply dividing the number of blue cards by the number of total cards?  That's the probability of drawing a blue card when drawing exactly *one* card.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming independence.

Without replacement:$$P=\frac3{3+4+2}\cdot\frac2{2+4+2}\cdot\frac1{1+4+2}=\frac1{84}$$ With replacement: $$P=\left(\frac3{3+4+2}\right)^3=\frac1{27}$$

Comment: I've got it now :)